# from wekzeug to gunicorn for Flask in a Docker container: stuck

Tags: docker, flask, containers, gunicorn, werkzeug

not sure what I'm doing wrong.
In my Flask code I have the usual

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

and at the bottom in the main:

```
app.run(host=config.get("host"), port=config.get("port"), use_reloader=False)
```

In my Dockerfile at the bottom I have:

```
# Run your app
EXPOSE 20899
#ENTRYPOINT poetry run python -m gunicorn --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm  --preload  'isagog_api.nlp_api:app' -b 0.0.0.0:20899
ENTRYPOINT poetry run python src/isagog_api/nlp_api.py
```

and with the version you see above you can run the app under wekzeug just fine.
Now I want to bring this to production and am testing it building the image with the poetry run line commented and the other ENTRYPOINT for gunicorn uncommented.
The app starts, but then get this type of messages:

```
isagog-nlp-gu  | [2023-10-19 17:49:10 +0200] [7] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
isagog-nlp-gu  | [2023-10-19 17:49:10 +0200] [7] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:20899 (7)
isagog-nlp-gu  | [2023-10-19 17:49:10 +0200] [7] [INFO] Using worker: sync
isagog-nlp-gu  | [2023-10-19 17:49:10 +0200] [62] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 62
isagog-nlp-gu  | [2023-10-19 17:49:42 +0200] [7] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:62)
isagog-nlp-gu  | [2023-10-19 17:49:43 +0200] [7] [ERROR] Worker (pid:62) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
isagog-nlp-gu  | [2023-10-19 17:49:43 +0200] [63] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 63
isagog-nlp-gu  | [2023-10-19 17:50:13 +0200] [7] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:63)
isagog-nlp-gu  | [2023-10-19 17:50:14 +0200] [7] [ERROR] Worker (pid:63) was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?
```

What am I doing wrong? Tried with different gunicorn worker types, with a longer timeout parameter etc but no go. Thanks

Comment: Interesting case. can you provide a minimal example maybe on github, so that w can reproduce the error and try to find a solution?

Comment: I would start by removing unnecessary source of complexity, like `peotry`, `--worker-tmp-dir` and `--preload` to see if that has any effect. It cloud be  permissions on the `/dev/shm` folder for example!

Comment: any solution @robert? I have the same problem?

Comment: @igo sadly no and not pursuing anymore for now. good luck

Comment: meanwhile I solved it by adding more workers: --workers=X

Comment: Very interesting. I had tried but failed. Can you write the type of workers or the entire line you're using? Thanks a lot